# Blow down map induced injection on homology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $\tilde X$ be the blow up of $X\subset \mathbb{CP^{n+1}}$ along some closed subscheme $C\subset X$, $f : \tilde X\to X$ be the blow down map, and $f_*:H_k(\tilde X)\to H_k(X)$ be the induced map on homology groups. Is it true that $f_*$ is injective?

**Edit**

Should add the condition that $X$ is of dimension $n$ and $C$ is of dimension $n-2$, and only consider the homology group of degree $n-2$.

Answer (score 1):

No!

Example: blowing up a point in $\mathbb{CP}^2$  gives $\widetilde{\mathbb{CP}^2}=\mathbb{CP}^2\#\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ so its $H_2$ is $\mathbb{Z}^2$, generated by the exceptional divisor $E$ and the $\mathbb{CP}^1$ at infinity, but $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^2)=\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by the $\mathbb{CP}^1$ at infinity.so $f_*\colon H_2(\widetilde{\mathbb{CP}^2})\to H_2(\mathbb{CP}^2)$ cannot be injective.
In fact $f$ shrinks the exceptional divisor $E$ to a point so $f_*[E]=0$ in $H_2$.

Maybe you are thinking about the map induced by the strict transform?

Comment: But anyway I see my original guess is no true. Please check the condition I add in my questions.

Comment: Yes you are right in the original case.

Comment: Have you forgotten some factor of 2 converting between the topological dimension (homology degree) and the dimension over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: No. More precisely, $dim_\mathbb C X=n$, $dim_\mathbb C C=n-2$ and degree of homology is $n-1$. (otherwise your previous counter example will still work)

Comment: If you blow up $\mathbb{P}^3$ along a line, the exceptional fiber over a point is a $\mathbb{P}^1$ which is a topological 2-sphere.  That should be nontrivial in homology but got killed by blowdown?

Comment: The exceptional fiber over a point should be $\mathbb P^2$, hence there is no nontrivial 2-sphere.

Comment: The normal bundle of a line in $\mathbb{P}^3$ has rank 2, so projectivizing gives $\mathbb{P}^1$ fibre, no? (Also, $\mathbb{P}^d$ has a $\mathbb{P}^1$ as the intersection of $d-1$ hyperplanes, so there are always nontrivial 2-spheres in such blowups)

Comment: Yes you are perfectly correct. I made some stupid mistakes. The degree of the homology group should be $n-2$. Sorry about this :)